# Android Share Image from Phone Gallery to Facebook using Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, gallery, uri, share

I am trying to have my Android Application share a URI image to facebook.  When using the picture parameter, it forces you to use a URL of a picture.  Since I am trying to share from my phones gallery, I was wondering if there was a way to have a URI read like a URL, or any other way to do this.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE:  I have updated this by adding my code that I am attempting to use.  I understand that I am not using the newly rolled out API of Facebook. I just want to be able to post a picture from my phone gallery to Facebook, and not a picture from URL.  Thank you!

```
private String[] arrPath;
int id = viewIt.getId();
if(facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                        params.putString("name", "AndroidApp");
                                        params.putString("caption", "Application for Android");
                                        params.putString("description", "This is a description");
                                        params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com/");
                                        params.putString("picture", "file://" + arrPath[id]);

                                        facebook.dialog(AndroidClass.this, "feed", params, new DialogListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancel() {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else {
                                        facebook.authorize(AndroidClass.this, new String[] {"email", "publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                Toast.makeText(AndroidClass.this, "fberror", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                Toast.makeText(AndroidClass.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                                                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                                                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires()); 
                                                editor.commit();

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancel() {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                Toast.makeText(AndroidClass.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }

                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open a stream to the image from the URI and post it that way using `ContentResolver`.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, photo, new Request.Callback());
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Comment: I still wasn't able to get it to go that way.  I'll post my code above.